# Windows 8 Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, windows-8, air

Full screen AIR application that plays 8 videos (mp4) in a loop for local community center.

This application runs flawlessly on an 9 year old dell inspiron zino hd (windows vista), and a 10 year old macbook pro for days on end without ever turning off the machine and screen.

The local community center recently bought a ASUS EB1036 that has windows 8 on it.

This machine will run for a couple hours but then the AIR app goes black.

I have added some display fields in a test version of the AIR app to see time played, total memory used, file being played, etc...

When ran on the ASUS, the screen eventually will go black and freezes to an extent however the timer keeps ticking showing time played.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried debugging on the ASUS?  Seeing if it throws any errors?   What of the memory usage right before it "goes black"?

Comment: Yeah... I have the task manager up where I am watching the CPU and Memory.  I also have some display fields within the AIR app that are displaying memory used, time, etc...  Nothing ever increases over the played time.  Every thing is steady as can be.  I have even gone as far as to trace out into another window within AIR where each and every function is being called.  My latest test is running the app by right clicking the app icon and run program in Windows Vista mode instead of Windows8... :\  we will see how it goes I guess.  Its so odd to me that it runs fine on 10 year old machines.

Comment: You can't use Scout?  It will tell you what happened.